# Folding removes syntax highlighting when editing *.twig files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, twig, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, folding

When editing *.twig files in mac osx Eclipse both syntax highlighting and folding are working fine on their own.  Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug/feature? When both are enabled, the syntax highlighting is shown for a second and when folding "kicks in" the highlighting is removed and all text turns black.

Syntax highlighting enabled:

[image]

Folding Enabled:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like this should be a bug report to whatever twig editor you're using.

Comment: Can you show us the twig part? You are just showing an HTML rendering here.

Comment: Haven't found it but seems like you should report this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Comment: Editor I'm using is Eclipse as stated in the header.

"Twig parts" have no effect. When file type is *.twig the colouring disappears. I also noticed that highlighting come back after closing and opening the the folding... but only for that part of the code. Rest is staying back/white.